# implement custom slider without extension magento

Tags: magento, slider

i want to implement bootstrap slider in magento dynamically without using any extension. so user can change images easily from admin without enter in any page. can anyone tell me what is coreect way to do this.

thanks

Comment: Show us what you did so far.

Comment: hello, actually i am using bootstrap slider and placed all divs and images in home page from admin(cms|pages). o want user can upload images easily not need to go to home page in cms section.